# Left Join сортировка запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Запрос должен выдавать имя группы и количество студентов у которых id_sex = 1(только группы в которых только мужчины). А выдает просто имя группы и количество мужчин в ней. Что не так то?

```
select
  grupa.name as grupa_name,
  count(student.id) as grupa_count
from student
left join grupa on grupa.id=student.id_grupa 
where student.id_sex = 1 
group by grupa_name
order by grupa_count
```

Comment: условие where работает до группировки, следовательно вы перед тем как группировать получаете только мужчин. и даже одного достаточно что бы после группирувки требуемая группа была. вам поможет условие `having max(student.id_sex) = 1` (после group by) (если нулевых и отрицательных id_sex не бывает)

Comment: Нет, не помогло .Может дело в group by? (группировать нужно не по grupa_name )?

Comment: а вы выведите max(student.id_sex) и посмотрите у каких групп какоие значения. и те ли это группы которые нужны

Comment: Выдает те же группы(в которых есть и женщины) но grupa_count везде 1. Выборка то у меня в начале правильная, просто нужно как то исключить из нее группы в которых есть id_sex = 2

Comment: А вы условие where убрали при этом ? а то ведь оно оставляет только мужчин и конечно max() уже не может дать 2

Comment: При удалении условия where показываются нужные группы но без должного количества? как теперь количество вывести?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  grupa.name as grupa_name,
  count(student.id) as total_count,
  SUM(student.id_sex = 1) AS male_count
from student
left join grupa on grupa.id=student.id_grupa 
group by grupa_name
/* HAVING total_count = male_count */
```

Comment: Да. Действительно нужно было сравнивать с суммой! Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы отфильтровываете по условию **where**, которое работает до группировки. Вам необходимо в процессе группировки получить значение, определяющее пол в группе (только мужчины). Учитывая то, что здесь sex имеет формат (1,0) вам достаточно определить минимальное значение **sex** в группе, если оно 1, то в группе нет ни единной девушки. Это условие стоит реализовать в **having**

**Код:**

```
select
  g.name as grupa_name,
  count(s.id) as grupa_count
  min(s.id_sex) as hasNotFemale
from student as s
left join grupa as g
on g.id=s.id_grupa  
group by grupa_name
having hasNotFemale = 1
```

p.s. в зависимости от диалекта sql синтаксис может незначительно отличаться.

**UPD для будущих поколений**

Если формат поля sex не (1, 0) то поле легко приводится к такому с помощью оператора case

Comment: А если поля sex - 1,2?  Группы девушек показывает правильно если поменять hasNotFemale = 2. А вот с мужчинами все тоже самое

Comment: можно использовать оператор case и менять любые значения на 0 и 1

select
max(CASE
    WHEN sex = 'Male' THEN 1
    WHEN sex = 'Female' THEN 0
END)
from table1